# Position built-in function with "test" instead of "pattern matching"?

Tags: list-manipulation

I read the doc about `Position` built-in function:

> "Position[expr, pattern] gives a list of the positions at which
>   objects matching pattern appear in expr."

For instance:

```
Position[{"a", "b", "A", "a", "B", "c", "b"}, "b"]
```

returns

```
{{2}, {7}}
```

However, I am desperately looking for a built-in function that works with a *test* instead of a *pattern matching*. To be clear I would like a built-in function that behaves as follow:

```
(* does not work, for illustration purpose *)
Position[{"a", "b", "A", "a", "B", "c", "b"},UpperCaseQ]
```

would return:

```
{{3}, {5}}
```

I am aware of the `Select` function,

```
Select[{"a", "b", "A", "a", "B", "c", "b"}, UpperCaseQ]
```

but it returns values and not positions (and I want positions!):

```
{"A", "B"}
```

**Question:** Do I miss read the doc, maybe such built-in function exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Position[UpperCaseQ /@ vars, True]
```

Answer (score 6):

I just found this:

```
Position[{"a", "b", "A", "a", "B", "c", "b"}, _String?UpperCaseQ]
```

is working.

---

**Update:** Albert Retey, just rightly commented that it works without the head check.

For instance:

```
Position[Range[10], _?OddQ]
```

is working.

Comment: that's something along the lines of what I was going to suggest. :)

Comment: @rcollyer, thanks. On my side it was not on purpose. I was annoyed by this and just found the solution I posted.

Comment: this would work equally well without the head-check, e.g.: `Position[{0.,-1,5,-5.3},_?Negative]`. That is probably just relevant for those cases where your entries do not all have the same head but I often use it without checking for the head, the typical test function would return false for non-matching entries anyway, cf.: `OddQ["a"]`

Comment: @AlbertRetey thanks for the constructive comment, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

```
vars = {"a", "b", "A", "a", "B", "c", "b"};

Position[Table[UpperCaseQ[vars[[i]]], {i, Length[vars]}], True]

(*{{3},{5}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I just found something that seems to work ( Position[{"a", "b", "A", "a", "B", "c", "b"}, _String?UpperCaseQ] )

Comment: @Picaud Vincent Nice!

Comment: Thanks, I only hope this can work in all cases, the syntax _String?UpperCaseQ is not the most natural one.

Comment: why? i find it elegant: it select all the string elements and test them with UpperCaseQ

Comment: @Alucard for instance Position[Range[10], _Number?OddQ] returns {}... I certainly miss something...

Comment: @PicaudVincent  try `Position[Range[10], _Integer?OddQ]`

Comment: @Alucard, good catch, that works. Thanks. My "Number" was something stupid, this is not the Head of "numbers"...

Comment: @PicaudVincent i suggest you to wait a little longer before accepting an answer, the experts may want to add their solution

Comment: @alucard thanks, I will do that next time... It is just that I am not very proud of this duh "question" :-/